# How to import module in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I have an angular application and I also created a module as npm package. This is the structure:

```
--otherModule
  --other-module.module.ts
  --index.ts
  --package.json
```

**index.ts:**

```
export { OtherModule } from './other-module.module';
```

**other-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ OtherComponent ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
})
export class OtherModule {
}
```

After running npm link I'm trying to use this module in my AppModule like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OtherModule } from 'other-module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    OtherModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

But then I'm getting the following error:

> Unexpected value 'OtherModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'.
>   Please add a @NgModule annotation.

It seems like the decorator doesn't work or something. Any ideas?

Comment: could you provide other-module.module.ts ?

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

`import { OtherModule } from 'other-module.module';` would work, you missed the module extension that you provided for the directory structure.

Comment: That's not the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it's resolved after deleting the node_modules of otherModule and npm-installing from the parent app.

However, one has to constantly install and uninstall the node_modules of the library (install is needed for building, testing, and for IDE to know the types in the dependencies) which makes development very cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue like this and I fixed it by removing the node_modules folder form inside the linked folder.

For you, the fix should be remove node_modules from within the `--otherModule` folder. this way, npm would not search inside it.

I do not know if is the same problem you are facing, but worth a try.

Comment: But then you are getting errors in your IDE because he does not know these libraries, no?

Comment: You should 1 - remove node_modules from you linked app, 2 - npm install to install the linked app and its dependencies. This whay, the linked app will have only the pkgs it uses and the angular pkgs would be placed in the root node_modules. This way you will have all references but avoid having angular pkgs in two node_modules folders (the app and the linked app).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks all right, I have simulated it in my machine and worked it. The only diference is that you should change the file from `other-module.module.ts` to `other.module.ts` or change your module name from `OtherModule` to `OtherModuleModule` and then update those references.

I Suggest you to create your components and modules through angular cli using the command `ng g c other` to component and `ng g m other` to module to keep the standard of the project.